# setState() is not working in flutter Getx default dialogbox

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

im trying to implement list of filterchips in get.defaultDialog() but the chip is not selected after the setstate() function. is it possible to create a stateful getx dialogbox in flutter Getx

```
Get.defaultDialog(
                                        title: "Select lable",
                                        content: Wrap(
                                            spacing: 8,
                                            runSpacing: 8,
                                            children:
                                                controller.lables.map((lable) {
                                              return FilterChip(
                                                  label: Text(lable),
                                                  selected:
                                                      filter.contains(lable),
                                                  onSelected: (val) {
                                                    if (val) {
                                                      filter.add(lable);
                                                    } else {
                                                      filter.removeWhere(
                                                          (element) {
                                                        return element == lable;
                                                      });
                                                    }
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                  });
                                            }).toList()),
                                        actions: <Widget>[
                                          TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Get.back();
                                            },
                                            child: const Text('Cancel'),
                                          ),
                                          TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            child: const Text('OK'),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new statefull class for body of your dialog and pass it like

```
 Get.defaultDialog(
      title: "Select lable",
      // pass statefull class which contain your dialog body
      content:DialogBody(labels:controller.labels),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('OK'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

now i make a new state full class which contain you dialog body

```
 class DialogBody extends StatefulWidget {
   DialogBody({super.key,required this.lables});
   List lables;
   @override
  State<DialogBody> createState() => _DialogBodyState();
}

 class _DialogBodyState extends State<DialogBody> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return  Wrap(
          spacing: 8,
          runSpacing: 8,
          children: widget.lables.map((lable) {
            return FilterChip(
                label: Text(lable),
                selected: filter.contains(lable),
                onSelected: (val) {
                  if (val) {
                    filter.add(lable);
                  } else {
                    filter.removeWhere((element) {
                      return element == lable;
                    });
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                });
          }).toList());
      }
    }
```

You can also pass some parameters to you class (dialog content/body)